# How to check for all empty input in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some form which are dynamically generated & have different id, so i thought  there could be something that will validate each input, here i what i did

```
$.fn.isBlank = function() {
    var fields = $("#exp0").serialize()
alert('something');
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (fields[i].value != '') {
            alert('testing');
            return false;
        }
    }
alert('testing2');
    return true;
};
```

But above script doesn't work i don't know why, even the alerts are not triggered

here is the full jquery

```
 $(document).on("submit", "#exp0", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
var postData = $("#exp0").serialize()
$.fn.isBlank = function() {
    var fields = $("#exp0").serialize()
alert('something');
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (fields[i].value != '') {
            alert('testing');
            return false;
        }
    }
alert('testing2');
    return true;
};
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/ajax/saveexp",
     data: postData,
      async: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      cache: false,
       success: function(msg)
         {
        bootbox.alert('Your Profile has been updated');
                }

      });
  });
```

Comment: use `$.fn.extend` to add new methods for jQuery instance, then `isBlank` should be called something like `$('#exp0').isBlank()`

Comment: @MarkoCen can i use something else instead of $.fn.extend or $.fn.isBlank to activate this function

Comment: if you want a static jQuery method, just use `$.isBlank`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be, that you first serialize the form fields (which results in a string) and then try to iterate over the fields in this string (which will not work).

Iterate over the form fields directly instead. With jQuery, you can do that easily:

```
$("#exp0").find("input").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === '') { ... }
});
```

Another note: defining a function `isBlank` is not enough, it must be called somewhere.
You could remove the declaration and do the check directly in place.

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/vq3y6bok/1/

Comment: if i use find("input").each then it will find all the input in the page i think? In my page there are 5,6 forms

Comment: By calling find() on the form, it searches only in this form, not on the page.

Comment: You could even use `$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) ...` and then `$(this).find("input")... ` to make it work for every form.

Comment: Thanks Joachim Schirrmacher

Comment: I added a complete example in the fiddle.